# How to live preview PHP using MAMP

Tags: php, wordpress, preview

I am creating a WP theme (for personal use only) and I need to be able to preview PHP files.

Here's where I'm at so far:
I use Adobe's Brackets.
I have a server on Bluehost.
I have downloaded FileZilla and linked it to my bluehost server.
I have created a directory on my bluehost server: /public_html/wp-content/themes/Cookie
I have downloaded an FTP Sync extension in Brackets, and synced it to the root directory of my theme (/public_html/wp-content/themes/Cookie).
I have installed MAMP on my mac (although never used it and have no idea what to do next).

I have contact Adobe Brackets and they have said this: "If you have a MAMP (or other PHP server) set up, you just need to change the File->Project Settings"

But I have no idea what to do now I have downloaded MAMP.

As you can probably tell, I'm a bit of a noob so please explain things delicately :)

Thanks in advance!!!!

Comment: You can't really "live preview" without WordPress because it will require dependencies. I'm not sure of an editor that would be even capable of doing that.

Answer (score 2):

download Wordpress from wordpress.org, [install it locally on your MAMP](http://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress_Locally_on_Your_Mac_With_MAMP), it shoud have a folder called www or data, reading the docs is recommended. Then, download your theme from your hosting and to the wp-content/themes/ folder, now start a new project, it's gonna be easier.

When your theme is ready, upload it to the server again.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but figured it out with the help of your question. 
So this is for brackets newcomers like myself :)

**Guide for Mac:**

**Setting up Server**

- Download and install MAMP
- Go to MAMP Preferences
- Change the "document root to your project

**Brackets Setting:**

- Open Brackets
- Make sure the "*Enable Experimental Live Preview*" IS OFF! (File > Enable...)
- Go to File > project setting
- copy and paste this default MAMP server address (http://localhost:8888/) [or change according to your MAMP setting]

Thats it you have got your live preview up and running!